# Update color of single point of GeometryModel3D Material rather than whole system of points

Tags: c#, wpf, colors

I'm having trouble getting my head around the colour/material system of C# WPF projects, currently I am updating the colour of an entire system of points on each update of the model when I would instead like to just update the colour of a single point (as it is added).

## AggregateSystem Class

```
public class AggregateSystem {
    // stack to store each particle in aggregate
    private readonly Stack<AggregateParticle> particle_stack;
    private readonly GeometryModel3D particle_model;
    // positions, indices and texture co-ordinates for particles
    private readonly Point3DCollection particle_positions;
    private readonly Int32Collection triangle_indices;
    private readonly PointCollection text_coords;
    // brush to apply to particle_model.Material
    private RadialGradientBrush rad_brush;
    // ellipse for rendering
    private Ellipse ellipse;
    private RenderTargetBitmap render_bitmap;

    public AggregateSystem() {
        particle_stack = new Stack<AggregateParticle>();
        particle_model = new GeometryModel3D { Geometry = new MeshGeometry3D() };
        ellipse = new Ellipse {
            Width = 32.0,
            Height = 32.0
        };
        rad_brush = new RadialGradientBrush();
        // fill ellipse interior using rad_brush
        ellipse.Fill = rad_brush;
        ellipse.Measure(new Size(32,32));
        ellipse.Arrange(new Rect(0,0,32,32));
        render_bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(32,32,96,96,PixelFormats.Pbgra32));
        ImageBrush img_brush = new ImageBrush(render_bitmap);
        DiffuseMaterial diff_mat = new DiffuseMaterial(img_brush);
        particle_model.Material = diff_mat;
        particle_positions = new Point3DCollection();
        triangle_indices = new Int32Collection();
        tex_coords = new PointCollection();
    }

    public Model3D AggregateModel => particle_model;

    public void Update() {
        // get the most recently added particle
        AggregateParticle p = particle_stack.Peek();
        // compute position index for triangle index generation
        int position_index = particle_stack.Count * 4;
        // create points associated with particle for circle generation
        Point3D p1 = new Point3D(p.position.X, p.position.Y, p.position.Z);
        Point3D p2 = new Point3D(p.position.X, p.position.Y + p.size, p.position.Z);
        Point3D p3 = new Point3D(p.position.X + p.size, p.position.Y + p.size, p.position.Z);
        Point3D p4 = new Point3D(p.position.X + p.size, p.position.Y, p.position.Z);
        // add points to particle positions collection
        particle_positions.Add(p1);
        particle_positions.Add(p2);
        particle_positions.Add(p3);
        particle_positions.Add(p4);
        // create points for texture co-ords
        Point t1 = new Point(0.0, 0.0);
        Point t2 = new Point(0.0, 1.0);
        Point t3 = new Point(1.0, 1.0);
        Point t4 = new Point(1.0, 0.0);
        // add texture co-ords points to texcoords collection
        tex_coords.Add(t1);
        tex_coords.Add(t2);
        tex_coords.Add(t3);
        tex_coords.Add(t4);
        // add position indices to indices collection
        triangle_indices.Add(position_index);
        triangle_indices.Add(position_index + 2);
        triangle_indices.Add(position_index + 1);
        triangle_indices.Add(position_index);
        triangle_indices.Add(position_index + 3);
        triangle_indices.Add(position_index + 2);
        // update colour of points - **NOTE: UPDATES ENTIRE POINT SYSTEM** 
        // -> want to just apply colour to single particles added
        rad_brush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(p.colour, 0.0));
        render_bitmap.Render(ellipse);
        // set particle_model Geometry model properties
        ((MeshGeometry3D)particle_model.Geometry).Positions = particle_positions;
        ((MeshGeometry3D)particle_model.Geometry).TriangleIndices = triangle_indices;
        ((MeshGeometry3D)particle_model.Geometry).TextureCoordinates = tex_coords;
    }

    public void SpawnParticle(Point3D _pos, Color _col, double _size) {
        AggregateParticle agg_particle = new AggregateParticle {
            position = _pos, colour = _col, size = _size;
        }
        // push most-recently-added particle to stack
        particle_stack.Push(agg_particle);
    }

}
```

where `AggregateParticle` is a POD class consisting of `Point3D position`, `Color color` and `double size` fields which are self-explanatory.

Is there any simple and efficient method to update the colour of the single particle as it is added in the `Update` method rather than the entire system of particles? Or will I need to create a `List` (or similar data structure) of `DiffuseMaterial` instances for each and every particle in the system and apply brushes for the necessary colour to each?

[The latter is something I want to avoid at all costs, partly due to the fact it would require large structural changes to my code, and I am certain that there is a better way to approach this than that - i.e. *there **MUST** be some simple way to apply colour to a set of texture co-ordinates, surely?!*.]

**Further Details**

- `AggregateModel` is a single `Model3D` instance corresponding to the field `particle_model` which is added to a `Model3DGroup` of the `MainWindow`.
- I should note that what I am trying to achieve, specifically, here is a "gradient" of colours for each particle in an aggregate structure where a particle has a `Color` in a "temperature-gradient" (computed elsewhere in the program) which is dependent upon order in which it was generated - i.e. particles have a colder colour if generated earlier and a warmer colour if generated later. This colour list is pre-computed and passed to each particle in the `Update` method as can be seen above.
- One solution I attempted involved creating a separate `AggregateComponent` instance for each particle where each of these objects has an associated `Model3D` and thus a corresponding brush. Then an `AggregateComponentManager` class was created which contained the `List` of each `AggregateComponent`. This solution works, however it is horrendously slow as each component has to be updated every time a particle is added so memory usage explodes - is there a way to adapt this where I can cache already rendered `AggregateComponent`s without having to call their `Update` method each time a particle is added?

Full source code (C# code in the `DLAProject` directory) can be found on GitHub: https://github.com/SJR276/DLAProject

Comment: @EvilTak But then how can this array of `Material`s be applied to the single `particle_model` instance of `AggregateSystem`? As far as I am aware, a `GeometryModel3D` only takes a single `Material` instance.

Comment: Sorry, that was a misunderstanding on my part. Read on:    I don't see what you're trying to do here. Are you implementing a particle system? If so, I'd recommend using separate models (technically just a triangle or quad) for each `Particle` and handle rendering for each particle separately.

Comment: @EvilTak Yes, it is essentially a particle system (with special properties) that is being implemented. I see, I shall have to take a look into that type of solution. I have added a link to the full source code on github if you want to see the rest of the project structure, there's too much code to post here.

Comment: Looking at what you want to achieve, I think it'll be better if you abstracted each `Particle` into its own unit and render each particle separately. I've forked the code and will try to run it to see exactly what you want to do after a good night's sleep.

Comment: @EvilTak That probably makes sense, I'll take a look at doing that then. Thanks!

Comment: @EvilTak I should mention, I attempted a solution whereby each `Particle` has its own `Model3D` and this worked - however it was far too inefficient as I needed to call `Update` of every single particle continuously to render the aggregate; if I was missing something whereby when a single particle is rendered its "properties" could be cached so I didn't need to continuously render them over and over then I would have a workable solution...

Comment: Why don't you try using OpenGL/MonoGame instead? Is it necessary to use WPF? A rendering library will make all of this a *lot* easier. Using a graphics engine (which handles culling and all that) will make it even easier.

Comment: @EvilTak Yeah I guess I could try using OpenGL or CUDA instead, I just started using WPF for this as it's generally easier for making interfaces but switching across to the above could be worth a try.

Comment: CUDA isn't a rendering library, FYI. It's a platform for running programs on specifically Nvidia GPUs. And making interfaces in MonoGame/OpenGL shouldn't be *too* hard, there must be some good resources/libraries out there. Plus, OpenTK/MonoGame is cross-platform (MonoGame is more easy to deploy on all platforms, incl. mobile apps).

Comment: @EvilTak I'll take a look into it, might require a fair amount of time for learning OpenGL but it could be worth it, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We create WPF 3D models for smallish point clouds (+/- 100 k points) where each point is added as an octahedron (8 triangles) to a MeshGeometry3D.

To allow different colors for different points (we use this for selecting one or a subset of points) in such a point cloud, we assign texture coordinates from a small Bitmap.

At a high level we have some code like this:

```
BitmapSource bm = GetColorsBitmap(new List<Color> { BaseColor, SelectedColor });
ImageBrush ib = new ImageBrush(bm) 
{ 
    ViewportUnits = BrushMappingMode.Absolute, 
    Viewport = new Rect(0, 0, 1, 1) // Matches the pixels in the bitmap.
};  
GeometryModel3D model = new GeometryModel3D { Material = new DiffuseMaterial(ib) };
```

and now the texture coordinates are just

```
new Point(0, 0);
new Point(1, 0);
```

... etc.

The colors Bitmap comes from:

```
// Creates a bitmap that has a single row containing single pixels with the given colors.
// At most 256 colors.
public static BitmapSource GetColorsBitmap(IList<Color> colors)
{
    if (colors == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("colors");
    if (colors.Count > 256) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("colors", "More than 256 colors");

    int size = colors.Count;
    for (int j = colors.Count; j < 256; j++)
    {
        colors.Add(Colors.White);
    }

    var palette = new BitmapPalette(colors);
    byte[] pixels = new byte[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        pixels[i] = (byte)i;
    }

    var bm = BitmapSource.Create(size, 1, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Indexed8, palette, pixels, 1 * size);
    bm.Freeze();
    return bm;
}
```

We also go to some effort to cache and reuse the internal Geometry structure when updating the point cloud.

Finally we display this with the awesome [Helix Toolkit](https://github.com/helix-toolkit).

Comment: Excellent, I'll need some time to digest all this but it looks useful

Comment: A few questions, what do `BaseColor` and `SelectedColor` represent here and how would I apply colours to this `List` argument during the `Update` method in order to pull the colour of each particle added and apply this `Color` to its respective position in the bitmap? Also, is there a reason for using Helix Toolkit over standard WPF Media3D?

Comment: I think you'd build the Bitmap with the whole list of colors you want to use beforehand. BaseColor and SelectedColor are fixed colors associated with the whole PointCloud. We just use two, but it would work with up to 256. Then the texturecoordinates of your Geometry are just points in the Bitmap matching the color you want to give the vertices. We just use the Helix Toolkit viewport for moving, zooming etc.

Comment: Hmmm, problem is I need a lot more colours than 256 as I can have up to 10000 particles in an aggregate (and possibly more in the future) which should each have their own colour based on the order they were generated - i.e. to achieve a colour-gradient of sorts.

Comment: I'm sure you can extend the Bitmap to have as many colors as you want - you just have to revisit exactly how the bitmap and TextureCoordinates relate.

Comment: A `BitmapPalette` cannot have over 256 colours though so this solution cannot realistically be extended to my use case.

Comment: Maybe you can use a Bitmap with a different image format...?

Comment: Yes, I guess I will have to do more research into this - seems WPF just doesn't have any simple ways of colouring given texture co-ordinates. Anyway, I'll mark this as accepted now.